# Correct approach to reference TypeScript compiled files using outDir

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

I have a simple app two `.ts` files that I compile using the following `tsconfig.js` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

Running the following command (at the root of the project)

```
tsc -p client --outDir public/js
```

Gives me the following directory structure and this is how I want it laid out

```
 myproj
      |
      |-- src
      | |-- tsconfig.js
      |   |-- app.ts
      |   |-- header.ts
      |
      |-- public
        |--js
            |
            |-- app.js
            |-- app.js.map
            |-- header.js
            |-- header.js.map
```

So far, so good.Then I reference my `app.js` file using `SystemJS` in my HTML file:

```
<script src="js/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script>
    System.config({
      packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}}
    });
    System.import('js/app.js');
</script>
```

I see a `404` in my dev tools:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/js/header 404 (Not Found)
```

What am I missing? Do I even need systemJS at this point or should I be referencing plain old JS files in my HTML file?

app.ts

```
import {bootstrap, Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {AppHeader} from './header';

@Component({
    selector: 'get-er-done',
    templateUrl: 'templates/app.html',
    directives: [AppHeader]
})
class AppComponent { }
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

header.ts

```
import {bootstrap, Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
declare var user: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    templateUrl: 'templates/app-header.html'
})
export class AppHeader {
    public luser = user;    
 }
```

Comment: provide if you have ny plnkr of your code it would be eaiser to find the problem by this. and secondly no Need to import `Bootstrap` in the header.ts file. we import bootstrap only in the root component.

Comment: the bootstrap in the `header.ts` was a side-effect of copy-pasting. :)

Comment: If you are using SystemJS maybe you should change "module": "commonjs" to "module": "systemjs" in the tsconfig.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the way I was setting up the package with `systemjs`

```
<script>
    System.config({
      packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}}
    });
    System.import('js/app.js');
</script>
```

I was setting up a package called `app` but instead it should have been called `js` since that is where all my transpiled JS files lived. The correct version looks like this:

```
<script>
    System.config({
      packages: {'js': {defaultExtension: 'js'}}
    });
    System.import('js/app');
</script>
```

I do not need the `.js` extension while importing.

Answer (score 1):

See file "systemjs.config.js" in root and check values for your project:
map -> app

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
paths: {
  // paths serve as alias
  'npm:': 'node_modules/'
},
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'public/js',
  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
  // other libraries
  'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
},
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
  app: {
    main: './app.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
    main: './index.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
  });
 })(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing? Do I even need systemJS at this point or should I be referencing plain old JS files in my HTML file?

No.

Change your systemjs config to :

```
System.config({
  "defaultJSExtensions": true,
});
```

Comment: It is serving all the js files in there. I can stick the entire URL and get to a js file. The only thing missing is the extension.

Comment: I did that but now I see a completely different issue. Looks like systemjs is now trying to find angular2/angular2 reference and is throwing a 404 - http://localhost:3000/angular2/angular2.js